# Schedule Job to Pull Data from Oracle DB to SQL Server DB on periodic basis

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have to pull data from a table in Oracle DB and load in to a table in SQL server DB.
I have created a DTS package that imports and load the data by linking two DBs.
Please advice on how to schedule a job to call the DTS package(on monthly basis) which I have created already with the required process flow.

Appreciate your help!
New bee

Answer (score 0):

You really should have googled this... I'm assuming you don't mean DTS (as in SQL 2000 Data Transformation Services), but rather .DTSX files in SSIS.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/

Comment: Thanks.I did referred this link but my requirement is to import data from Oracle Db in to SQL server db.

Comment: The source is a CSV file in the link you have provided. But my requirement is the Data import from Oracle DB. Any help please. Thanks!

Comment: The link is simply scheduling an SSIS package.  What the package does shouldn't matter for creating a job.